# Exe Unpack or Process Spy - Getting process internals

Tags: decompilation, unpacking, process

I want to rewrite a application tool in C# that is written in **VB6**. This application does not work in windows 8/10 due to some compatibility issues.

It is an old game server management tool. This application read and writes to another process memory(a game).

I want the memory address to which the tool write/read from.

The tool is only **42kb.** and use **kernel32.dll** to read game process memory.

I tried to decompile this application from publically available decompiler but it didn't work. The file is packed with some **PE-Pack was released by ANAKiN**.

I also tried to read game memory values but unable to figure out which values i need because of a large amount of values.

**Is there any way i can spy/spectate on this tool, to find out what it is requesting from kernel32 library. or what external memory addresses it is reading from or writing to ?.**

Or there is any unpacker tool that can unpack the file so i can decompile it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to monitor the application with [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) to see what parameters it supplies to [`ReadProcessMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553.aspx) and [`WriteProcessMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674.aspx).

[image: API Monitor]

Comment: ok i will try that